# Can const variables be modified from elsewhere not known at compile time

Tags: c, linker, compiler-construction, constants

If const is a compile time construct, it would mean that only the compiler will ensure that for example if a variable is declared as const, this variable is read only and it is not attempted to be modified by the rest of the code being compiled?

What about if a const variable is a global variable in our code, and our code links to a dynamic library at run time which attempts to write to it? , or if an ISR attempts to update it, which was not in our compiled code?

I believe the compiler can mark const variables to be loaded into the read only data section which would prevent any changing of the variable, but what if it doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: `const` *might* be compile-time constants *or* run-time constants. It depends on context.

Comment: As for your problem, if you for any reason cast away the `const` then you open yourself up to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) from either your own or from third-part code as it might attempt to modify the data. Just don't cast away `const` and you should be (relatively) safe. Of course, nothing stops third-part code to cast it away, but that's out of your control, and will lead to UB.

Comment: But even from a dynamic library which implementation details are not known at compile time of our code, if there is an attempt to write to the const global variable from the dynamic library which is defined in our code, even without casting const  away, could it still write to it?

Comment: If something externally modifies the variable that is declared as `const` (and not `const volatile`), the behaviour is undefined. There are no "what ifs"

Comment: How could a third-party library write to your constant data without casting away the `const`? How would it even *know* about your data unless you provide it? And if you provide it using the `const` qualifier then you should expect that the library doesn't do something bad and attempt to modify the data. And if it tries to modify constant data, then you should throw it away and never use it again (after notifying the author about the issue of course).

Comment: @Engineer999 It could. But then the behavior is undefined. One of the uses of the term "undefined behavior" is to have a good default answer to what-if questions. If someone does something that's not reasonable the C standard doesn't promise that the program behaves in any reasonable way. You are running in an environment where things are allowed to do anything. The unknown dynamic library could be rewriting the code for your functions. When unreasonable things happen, reasonable results can not be guaranteed. Modifying a const qualified object is one of those unreasonable things.

Comment: Also, a const variable *could* be modified from something *known* at compile time. You can cast const away etc. The behaviour of course would be undefined, but it doesn't mean that it cannot be modified. The C standard doesn't even say that a program that attempts to modify `const` objects must not compile - it only says that a diagnostics message must be produced for certain operations, and that compiler is allowed to successfully compile *even an **invalid** program*.

Comment: If this is a genuine concern for you, not a hypothetical, then you should look into implementation-specific protections.  For instance, you might well be able to prevent the variables in question from being referenced by any external symbols in the final binary.  Or you may be able to use a linker script that ensures that the variable is placed in a read-only segment.  But the C language itself does not provide a way to specify those things, nor does it answer the "what happens if ..." question.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your answers

Comment: BTW: You should be aware that `const` does not mean "constant". It only means "read only". There might be some hardware registers accessed via `volatile const uint32_t * Timer1_p;` where the content might change between consecutive reads.

Comment: I remember a bug in Microsoft's Visual Studio 5 (16 odd years ago?) where it was easy to modify a string *literal*, never mind a `const`.  If you have a duff compiler, if someone has access to your process address space, or even your executable, all bets are off.

Comment: In C specifically `const` objects are not compile-time constants at all. Conceptually in C `const` values are treated as run-time values. Nevertheless, `const` object are not modifiable and compilers are allowed to optimize the code under that assumption.

Comment: @AnT I've been reading that const is only for the compiler so it will make sure our code does not try to write to the variable anywhere. If it is run-time, does the compiler generate special assembly code for when accessing the variable then?

Answer (score 4):

> the compiler will ensure that for example if a variable is declared as const, this variable is read only and it is not attempted to be modified by the rest of the code being compiled?

Yes, as far as the compiler is able to tell. If your code attempts to write to a `const`-qualified variable, you will get a compiler error. If you dodge type correctness by for example casting away the const qualifier, then all bets are off.

> What about if a const variable is a global variable in our code, and our code links to a dynamic library at run time which attempts to write to it? , or if an ISR attempts to update it, which was not in our compiled code?

Then it should not have been const qualified, or the compiler will make strange assumptions and generate incorrect code.

However, there exist cases where a  `const` variable may be updated from the outside world - it could be a read-only hardware register or an EEPROM memory cell etc.

To prevent the compiler from doing strange assumptions in such special cases, you can then combine `const` and `volatile`. All variables that may be updated from an external source, such as hardware or an ISR, should therefore always be declared as `volatile`.

Comment: The actual rule is that attempting to modify an object **defined** as const-qualified is undefined. A function could be passed a pointer to a const-qualified type, and, if the original object was not defined with const, then the function may cast away the const and modify the object.

Comment: My understanding is that const is only for the compiler so it will make sure we do not try to write to the variable anywhere in our code? Does the compiler however also generate special assembly code for when accessing the const variable to ensure that it is read-only?

Comment: @Engineer999 That depends on the system and sometimes variable scope. On pure RAM-based systems such as PC, `const` is mostly for the programmer. On microcontrollers with true flash ROM for example, the `const` keyword will mean that the variable will end up in ROM rather than RAM. Unless it has local scope, when it may or may not end up in ROM.